# Problem with my doubly linked list insert function

Tags: c++, insert, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to finish up a assignment for my data structures c++ class. I have to define a double linked list of functions(like insert() size() remove() ) that was provided by my instructor. The instructor also includes the main file which runs tests on my code to see if it works.

I'm receiving his error message:
* Starting dlist tests *
Checking empty list...
FAILED: size of empty list is != 0.

I tried to rewrite the definition of the size() and insert() function and Im not understanding why im getting his error.

my instructors test code:

```
bool test_empty() {
    std::cout << "Checking empty list...\n";
    dlist e;
    if(!verify(e))
        return false;
if(e.size() != 0) {
    std::cout << "FAILED: size of empty list is != 0.\n";
    return false;
}

if(!e.empty()) {
    std::cout << "FAILED: empty list is not .empty().\n";
    return false;
}

return true;
}
```

my code for implementations:

```
 void insert(node *previous, int value){
    if(previous == nullptr){
        node* n = new node;
        n->value = value;
        n->prev = previous;
        n->next = nullptr;
        return;
        }
    node* n = _head; //made a pointer to start at the head
    while( n!= previous )//make n go down the list until it hits previous
        {n = n->next;}
    node* store_next = n->next; //store the address of the prev pointer of the next node
    node* a = new node;//create the node that will be inserted
    a->value = value;
    n->next = a;// the pointer n points to the new node
    a->prev = n; //the prev in the new node points to the previous
    a->next = store_next; //the next in the new node points to the next node
    store_next->prev = a; //the next node's prev points to the new inserted node
}
 int size() const{
        node* n = _head;
        int size = 0;
        while(n != nullptr){
            size++;
            n = n -> next;
        }
        return size;
    }
```

Heres my default constructor and double linked list struct that my professor requires I use

```
class dlist {
  public:
    dlist() {
    }

struct node {
    int value;
    node* next;
    node* prev;
};
```

Comment: If the empty test is failing then it must be that the default constructor is wrong. Do you have a default constructor? If so you should post it. There are errors in `insert` as well. But lets start with the constructor. It would also be good to see the `dlist` definition.

Comment: The question lacks a [mre]. Take a closer look at `insert`. It doesn't seem to update the head pointer if the list is empty. Also, if you have a doubly linked list, there is no need to search for anything. You have pointers to the next and the previous nodes in each node. You can use them to get all of the nodes you need to insert.

Comment: Your default constructor should initialise _head to nullptr. `dlist() : _head(nullptr) {
    }` That should fix the empty test error.

Comment: thank you john, it did fix the error. Can you please explain to me were I made errors in my insert function?